# (gvim 8271) IBUS-WARNING

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I was calling a function multiple times using a single thread, and i was locking the resource inside the function  and I was creating some file and dint unlock it while returning from the function, and I found the below problem when tried to open the created file, what does this mean ? can somebody explain

```
>output: 
>(gvim:8271): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/user/.config/ibus/bus is not root
```

Answer (score 2):

i ran "sudo apt-get purge ibus", then installed fcitx.
when i ran gvim and closed it, the same warning output.

Fixed:
rm -rf /home/user/.config/ibus/bus

everything ok!